# parse error on input `in' Haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to type Haskell source file this code from ghci

```
ghci> let x = 3; y = "!" in show x ++ y
```

and transform my code to this

```
x = 3
y = "!" in show x ++ y
```

but got an error message like

> parse error on input `in'

How can I avoid the error and fix my code?

Comment: `in` cannot be used without `let`. Add `result = show x ++ y` or similar.

Comment: `let x = 3; y = "!" in show x ++ y` is actually `let { x = 3; y = "!" } in show x ++ y`. You can write that with whichever line-breaks you want, but you can't omit the `let`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon does not separate two independent assignments as you might expect from other languages; it serves as a replacement for a newline *and* the following indentation.

```
let x = 3; y = "!" in show x ++ y
```

is the layout-free version of

```
let x = 3
    y = "!"
in show x ++ y
```

where the indentation of `y = "!"` is significant.